# Can't mount an EBS to a particular EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs

I have three EC2 instances. I want to attach an EBS volume to one of the instances. Alas, when I go to the EBS volume and click attach, the drop down list of instances does not include the instance I wish to attach it to. There are only two instances on the list. Why is the instance missing from the list?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the instance in a different availability zone from the EBS volume?

Comment: Thanks. I didn't see the instance zone information before, it's only in the details view.